# Transfer data from Excel to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Problem statement: To transfer data from Excel to SQL Server.

I have a 64 bit system and 64 bit Microsoft Excel Installed. To make Excel Connection Manager work, I downloaded AccessDatabaseEngine.exe from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255. I tried to see if it works with AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe and it didn't, so I just installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe as you cannot install both apparently. In that way I was able to match columns and do things as required.

Then when I ran the project it throws errors as following-

```
Information: 0x4004300A at Data1, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0209303 at Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 3": The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
Error: 0xC001002B at Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 3": The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219816
Error: 0xC020801C at Data1, DataImportFile [20]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 3" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data1, SSIS.Pipeline: DataImportFile failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data1, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data1: There were errors during task validation.
```

I tried to see many videos on Youtube and went through some blogs. But I am unable to understand the situation here. What could be missing here?

Comment: `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered` - you need to specify the same version of ACE as you have installed. If this is thrown by SSIS wizard, then you need to upgrade SSIS or find an earlier version of ACE driver. I believe Ace 12.0 is from office 2010.

Comment: This may help you: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/excel-drivers-for-ssis-package and this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197087/ssis-ace-oledb-12-0-driver-issue